# Why does the mean squared error function require variables of the same shape?

Tags: data-science, mean-square-error

If we pass the training variable and the testing variable into the mean squared error function, then won't those variables necessarily have different shapes because of the train_test_split function? If so, then how can we use the mean_squared_error function to evaluate the accuracy of our model? If I am misunderstanding anything, then please let me know. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you for example look at the mean squared error in the sklearn package, read the documentation:

> sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None, 
>   multioutput=’uniform_average’)

The inputs are not the training and testing variable, but the real test labels variable and the predicted test labels. These naturally have the same shape.